# Decrypt folder, that was encrypted using EncFS, on Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, encryption

So this is my setup: I use Ubuntu (11.04, but this shouldn't matter) to encrypt my secret folder. I sync this folder using Ubuntu One (Dropbox would be possible too). Now I want to have it on my Android (not rooted) too.

But how do I decrypt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boxcryptor is in alpha stage now. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.boxcryptor.android

Answer (score 3):

[Encdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mrpdaemon.android.encdroid) available from Google Play Store, can do what you want with Dropbox:

> Encdroid is a file manager application for Android devices to keep your files encrypted on Dropbox or the local storage of the device. It is compatible with EncFS so volumes created with Encdroid can be accessed on Windows/MacOS/Linux desktop and laptops and vice versa.

[image: Screenshot 01] [image: Screenshot 02]

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried it yet, but Cryptonite (on [GitHub](https://github.com/neurodroid/cryptonite) and [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite); currently beta) may be an option.